# Relabelling Prometheus operator default alert

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

I want to relabel Kubenodeunreachle alert so I can drop this alert as we dont need it and its only creating more noise in the alerts channel.I think I need to include this relabelling under additionalScrapeConfigs: in Prometheus config..Please let me know if its correct..

```
additionalScrapeConfigs:
  - job_name: kube-state-metrics
    metric_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__name__]
      regex: '(KubeNodeUnreachable)'
      action: drop
```

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml#L1936 ?

Comment: I saw it now...But how to specify job name in this? I tried following https://medium.com/quiq-blog/prometheus-relabeling-tricks-6ae62c56cbda

Comment: In [prometheus documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/) you can see that you cannot specify  job_name for alerts.

Comment: thankyou..let me try that